# Search a range of strings in a range of cells

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells B1:F1 that each contain a different string. I want to find rows that the respective cells don't contain the string in the range, so that I can see, for example, that in row 2 cell B2 contains the string in B1, C2 contains C1 and so on.

[image]

> {=FIND(B1:F2,B2:F2)}

reurns #VALUE only if all the cells don't contain the string in the corresponding cell. I'm looking for a way to find rows that at least one of the cells doesn't contain the string in the cell above it in the top row. I'm looking for rows that have a cell that might have been shifted so that some cells will contain a string from a different header cell but not the one above it (e.g. C4 contains D1 but not C1)

Comment: Is `=OR(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1:F1,B2:F2)))` (CSE) what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like that but the result of that formula is FALSE for every row when make it an array and TRUE for every row if it isn't an array. most of the rows do contain the strings but some don't.

Comment: The formula I suggested returns FALSE if at least one cell in row 2 does not contain string from the cell above. If that is not what you need maybe you should edit your question and include sample input and formula results.

Comment: I added a sample of my data. I hope this helps clear up my question.

Comment: Using the formula you suggested returns TRUE even in rows that are similar to rows 4 and 5 of my sample data

Answer (score 1):

This gives a count of how many match (should be 5 if all of them match)

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER((FIND(B$1:F$1,B2:F2))))
```

entered as an array formula.